# Error : mysqli::real_connect(): (08004/1040): Too many connections [CodeIgniter v3]

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I have some problems in my site, I got an error too many connections .

Screenshot : http://pasteboard.co/Hz7QJQR.png

the Backtrace said my error in my `__construct`, model function `list_slider` and my model on `get function`:

this is my controller code :

```
<?php 

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Beranda extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'html'));
            $this->load->model(array('slider_model', 'slider_2_model', 'group_model', 'contact_model'));
    }

    public function index()
    {
            $data['slider_data'] = $this->slider_model->list_slider();
            $data['slider_2_data'] = $this->slider_2_model->list_slider();
            $data['group_data'] = $this->group_model->list_group();
            $data['contact_data'] = $this->contact_model->list_contact();
            $data['title'] = 'Kitchenware Equipments & Utensiles - norwinskitchenware.com';
            $this->load->view('fend/view_beranda', $data);
    }

}

?>
```

and this is my model **[UPDATE]**:

```
<?php
    class Slider_model extends CI_Model {

        function list_slider()
        {

                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('slider');
                $query = $this->db->get();
                $this->db->close();
                return $query->result();
        }
     }
?>
```

I already set `'pconnect' => FALSE` and `mysql.allow_persistent = OFF`

What should I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In your model you should close the connection for your function.

And If you do it in your Controller

```
public function __destruct() {  
    $this->db->close();  
}
```

You shall close it by `__destruct()`

Comment: I have updated my answer :) Sorry for not noting your question fully

Comment: I just try it, and nothing happens dude :(

Comment: Where are you doing the db Operations in Model or Controller ?

Comment: Of course in Model, you should check my post details

Comment: Yes, you have given the code that you have in the model. If you have it in the controller the use `_destruct()` also inside your model i.e., `function list_slider()` you should close it manually by `$this->db->close();` for all your functions .. Have you did this ?

Comment: Did you mention that I should put `$this->db->close();` `after $query = $this->db->get();` ??

Comment: I mean that, I guess it was in my answer :p `In your model you should close the connection for your function.`

Comment: I already try it, but nothing happens dude :( stressfull haha

Comment: Ah, I believe that you are doing it in the right files which you see in output.. :) Do you use  `reconnect();` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78636/discussion-between-tableman-and-sulthan-allaudeen).

Answer (score 3):

We don't need to use `$this->db->close()` like Sulthan Allaudeen telling. Because CI & some function connect db in present have config support for auto close when manipulation complete.

In codeigniter 3.1.2 i found out in `application/config/database.php`
property `$db['default']['pconnect']` is mean hold process after connect or we can explain like default of CI "Whether to use a persistent connection".

This value should be have value is `FALSE`.

Because if it value is `TRUE`. Your code access some time and have access to Database reach to limit connection of database(max_connections in `/etc/my.cnf`) we will be can't connect again and will output error:
`mysqli::real_connect(): (08004/1040): Too many connections`

Answer (score 3):

1. First check your connection limit.

   ```
    SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections';
   ```
2. Second check your current connection.

   ```
    SHOW STATUS LIKE 'max_used_connections';
   ```

Solution:
Temporarily => `SET GLOBAL max_connections = 512;`

Permanently => /etc/my.cnf  change this (max_connections = 512)

For CentOS/RHEL 6: `service mysqld restart`

For CentOS/RHEL 7: `systemctl restart mysqld`