# Too Many Connections Error in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Just want to ask how can I avoid the "Too Many Connections" Error in Codeigniter 3.1.13? I already tried to set the value of pconnection to FALSE like on the database setup below:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'port'     => 3306,
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'db_name',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8mb4',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

I also tried to close database connections using `$this->db->close();` and Codeigniter documentation said that:

> While CodeIgniter intelligently takes care of closing your database
> connections

But still Im facing this error. Any help will be appreciated!

When I checked the SHOW PROCESSLIST in mysql. even if I just loaded my header and footer in our website it opens a lot of threads and most of it was in 'Sleep' state.

[image]

Comment: which php and mysql version are you using?

Comment: and is the error  occuring on localhost or production server, if production server, is it a shared server, cloud, ...?)

Comment: @Vickel It's happening in Localhost and Production but what we do in production is to add more seconds in wait_timeout, What our project's/codeigniter issue is that it opens a lot of database connection.

Comment: your issue seems to be discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424208/error-mysqlireal-connect-08004-1040-too-many-connections-codeigniter. And in the CI-forum a super mod says: [*Then the only other thing that might help is to get the server admin to raise the number of connections.*](https://forum.codeigniter.com/showthread.php?tid=72649&pid=361074#pid361074)

Comment: @Vickel is there anything I can do to codeigniter so that it will not run many threads in mysql?

Comment: Don't think you can do anything in CI. Anyway I found some more info on mysql changes you can apply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4079589/2275490, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53230514/2275490 and also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47131/how-to-get-rid-of-maximum-user-connections-error